# Very high iowait when using 4TB disk

Tags: hard-drive, performance, fsck

I have an older PC that I use as a host for some VM and docker containers. So far the system was working fine until a few days ago. It started to be very slow and iowait in glances was consistently in the red with 30-40%. The system is Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS and fully up-to-date.

The PC has a 500GB SSD and a 4TB normal HDD with 16GB of RAM. Nothing too fancy, but as I said, it worked just fine. The Virtualbox VMs were all stored on the 4TB HDD. The VMs (all Ubuntu servers) were behaving so slow that I consistently had timeouts and a simple `apt update` would take 2-3 minutes. Surprisingly the HDD led on the PC was constantly on.

I have moved all the VMs VDI files to my NAS, and moved one persistent volume from a MySQL docker container off the 4TB disk. Suddenly, the performance of the VMs and the docker container was back normal again, so I assume it is the 4TB disk that is causing the problem.

I first ran `sudo badblocks -v /dev/sda > badsectors.txt` but that didn't show any bad sectors. It came back with 0 errors.

I then unmounted the disk, and excluded the drive from `/etc/fstab`. After a reboot, I ran `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda1`.

Surprisingly, this is what I got:

```
user@vs01:~$ sudo fsck -f /dev/sda1
[sudo] password for user:
fsck from util-linux 2.34
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/sda1: 298/244195328 files (9.4% non-contiguous), 91221367/976754176 blocks
```

The disk is clean and does not have any errors, yet there is a clear performance issue. SmartMonitor also shows no issues.

```
user@vs01:~$ sudo smartctl --all /dev/sda
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-51-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     TOSHIBA DT02ABA400
Serial Number:    X991S1DQS75H
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000039 995602197
Firmware Version: KQ000A
User Capacity:    4,000,787,030,016 bytes [4.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.3, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sat Oct 17 13:09:11 2020 HKT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                                        was never started.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (  39) The self-test routine was interrupted
                                        by the host with a hard or soft reset.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                (  120) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 510) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Always       -       6161
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       7
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   094   094   000    Old_age   Always       -       2584
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0033   100   100   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       7
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       5
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       832
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       37 (Min/Max 23/52)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
220 Disk_Shift              0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
222 Loaded_Hours            0x0032   094   094   000    Old_age   Always       -       2529
223 Load_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
224 Load_Friction           0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
226 Load-in_Time            0x0026   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       878
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0001   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Interrupted (host reset)      70%      2561         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Is there anything else that I could try/check to find the cause of these slow performance? At the moment the VMs run off the NAS, which is working fine, but somehow I'd like to make use of the 4TB disk. And I would assume, a local disk should perform faster than a connection of the network, no?

EDIT:

I copied back one VM and this is what I get now from the `iostat -x 1`

```
Device            r/s     rkB/s   rrqm/s  %rrqm r_await rareq-sz     w/s     wkB/s   wrqm/s  %wrqm w_await wareq-sz     d/s     dkB/s   drqm/s  %drqm d_await dareq-sz  aqu-sz  %util
sda            381.00   1740.50     7.00   1.80    1.38     4.57    9.00   2568.00    36.00  80.00    2.44   285.33    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.36  68.80
```

My disk is a 5400 spindle, so it's even slower...

Do I have 381 read operations per sec? Or which column is the read/write operations?

Answer (score 0):

When it is slow, run:

```
iostat -x 1
```

How many read and write operations per second do you get and at what %util?

A 7200 rpm disk is only good for about 120 IOPS, so if you are getting this many read + write operations per second combined or more, it's not a fault, mechanical disks are just painfully slow for random workloads.

You can use `iotop` to see which process is using up the most disk I/O.

Comment: I edited the question above with the results. I copied back one VM (with Grafana/Elasticsearch) and initially after the startup I had the above values. A bit later the activity is reduced.

Comment: Yes you are pushing 381+9 read+write IOPS. It means most of your operations are mergable/sequential. HDDs are slow, not much you can do to speed it up. It will get worse with more VMs because they will compete for I/O and fewer competing operations will be mergable.

Comment: With 3 VMs having the files on the 4TB disk running, the average r/s + w/s are in the single digits and the %util is around 2-3% max. So it seems when these VMs run more or less idle, it can cope fine, but if either one or more are getting busier, it might deteriorate quickly.
That's good to know, so I will be more careful to not update/upgrade them all together. I can't upvote your reply as I don't have enough reputation.